# JavaScript is converting a String to a String and causing an error

Tags: javascript, implicit-conversion

I have a Delphi app with some embedded JS.  I have a Function

```
function PlaceRecords(Lat, Lang, RecordNum, Dist, IconNo){
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(Lat,Lang);
    PutMarker(IconNo, Lat, Lang, "Record " + RecordNum + " at "  +Dist + " miles");
}
```

As long as does not have with a letter in the RecordNum. I pass in all the arguments as strings but for some reason, JS wants to convert RecordNum to an number.  How can I suppress this. Using IE 8.

Comment: How do you mean it converts it to a number? please provide an example of the kind of data you're passing in, what's happening to them, and what the string vs. number problem is about.

Comment: I call a procedure PlaceRecords(sLat, sLon, RecordNum, Dist, IconNo);
which calls 
procedure TfrmMain.PlaceRecords(Lat,Lon,RecordNum, Dist:string; IconNo:integer);
begin
   HTMLWindow2.execScript(Format('PlaceRecords(%s,%s,%s,%s, %s)',[Lat,Lon, RecordNum, Dist, IntToStr(IconNo)]), 'JavaScript');
end;

All the arguments are Strings.  I pass in 51210876 It plots the Record and displays the marker.  If a record has an Alpha in it e.g. A51210876, I get the error "Error: 'A51210876' is undefined "
nothing in the code has changed.  Just that the field now contains an 'A'.  This is a Script Error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well (based on your reply to my comment), if you could see the Javascript your code is generating, it would look something like this:

```
PlaceRecords(45.5262404, -122.6810841, A51210876, 123, 456);
```

Now do you see the problem?

You may be starting out with a bunch of strings, but you're not enclosing them as quotes, so Javascript doesn't consider them strings. `51210876` works because it's a number--even if you put it in quotes, it would be handled almost the same by Javascript. But as with most languages (I haven't written Pascal in almost 30 years but I'm certain it's the same), `A51210876` is going to be considered an identifier name rather than a value, since it begins with an alpha character.

Assuming you can freely place double-quotes inside single quotes, I suggest you try something like this:

```
procedure TfrmMain.PlaceRecords(Lat,Lon,RecordNum, Dist:string; IconNo:integer);
begin
    HTMLWindow2.execScript(Format(
        'PlaceRecords(%s, %s, "%s", "%s", "%s")',
        [Lat,Lon, RecordNum, Dist, IntToStr(IconNo)]),
        'JavaScript'
    );
end;
```

I know that lats and longs are numbers so I didn't place them in quotes. I don't know what sort of data the last two arguments contain, so I put them in quotes too. I imagine you could probably put them all in quotes, because any Javascript down the line that expects a number "should" be ensuring the value is actually treated as a number.

Note that in Javascript, strings can be enclosed by single OR double-quotes, which is pretty convenient at times like this.

Comment: Actually I figured it out a while ago but I will give you credit for it since you have it right.  Yes, I encapsulated the RecordNum in double quotes and all is well but you right, in that all the strings should be in double quotes.
Coming from a strongly typed language, implicit typing throws me.
Thanks for your help and explanation.

Comment: Happy to help, and thanks for the up-vote! Would you please mark my answer as correct? It's always good to have an answer posted for the next person who comes along with a similar problem and finds your question (and for this reason, you are even allowed to answer your own questions on StackOverflow).